# Нужно перевернуть строку c++

Tags: c++

С клавиатуры вводится строка символов, представляющая собой предложение со знаками препинания (точка, запятая, восклицательный знак). Вывести на экран предложение, получающееся из исходного изменением порядка букв на обратный в каждом слове с сохранением знаков препинания.
Вот код:

```
void reverse(char s[], int i, int j)  //переворот слова
{
    if (s[i] == '.' || s[i] == ',' || s[i] == '!' || s[i] == ' ')
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            i--;
            if (s[j] == s[i])
                break;
            if (j >= i)
                break;
            swap(s[j], s[i]);
        }
    }
}
int searchBegWord(char s[], int lenght, int pos)  //поиск начала слова
{
    for (int i = pos; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != '.' && s[i] != ',' && s[i] != '!' && s[i] != ' ')
        {
            int beg = i;
            return beg;
        }
    }
}
void reverseWord(char s[], int lenght, int i, int beg)  //переворот предлож.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '.' || s[i] == ',' || s[i] == '!' || s[i] == ' ')
        {
            reverseWord(s, lenght, searchBegWord(s,lenght,0) , i );
        }
    }
}
```

Нельзя использовать классы. У меня почему-то переворачивает только первое слово и всё. Не получается перевернуть предложение. В чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зачем вы передаете в `reverseWord` параметр `i`, который не используете? (это намек!)

Comment: Не только в ошибках дело, но и подход неправильный.  Попробуйте так:  напишите на бумаге что и как  должно произойти для получения результата, а потом написать все это на языке программирования.  Например,  у вас три функции, и все выполняют проверку одного и того же условия (тоже намек)